# How do I pack the resulting PDF a bit more?

Tags: spacing

I have written a document, and somewhere for some reason there is a lot of space, probably because something that latex deems crucial cannot be included in the same page without cutting it in the middle or so. This creates a large spacing before and after a section header and I just don't know how to avoid that.

Is there a way to "pack" the pdf more so there are no spaces, other than tinkering around with text, using hspace, etc.

Is there a way to enforce latex to not use too much spacing between paragraphs / headers even if it thinks it is ok?

No MWE, because I would have to give the whole document, I think - I don't know how to create a small examples that has this issue.

Comment: https://ctan.org/pkg/savetrees?

Comment: Add `\raggedbottom` right after `\begin{document}`

Comment: uh, that leaves space at the bottom, I guess because it can't fit a tcolorbox in that space. frustrating.

Comment: You must be able to make a small example. Latex page breaking is very localised it essentially only looks at one potential page break at a time. So if you have a page with an unexpected amount of white space, the item at the top of the next page does not fit. If you think it should fit, make a small two page example and someone can debug.

Comment: The whole idea of the float mechanism is to allow things to move automatically to avoid bad white space at page breaks, so if you have a large unbreakable tcolorbox, the standard answer to your question would be to put it in a `figure` so that it did not  obstruct page breaking.

Comment: A tcolorbox can be configured to be a floating object without including it in a figure or a table. See  section 4.13 of the manual  of `tcolorbox`  (page 79).